# How is 置く used here?

Tags: meaning, verbs

A dialogue between a monk and a shogun (fiction), fragment for context:

> Shogun: 「生きておれば死を望み、死に果てれば生を望む……全く、御坊に言われるまでもない。　人の心の働きというのは本当に勝手なものよ。どこまでも満足せぬように出来ておる」
>
> Monk: 「であればこそ、人は満足を求めてあがき、自らを高めるのでござる。　満ち足りた人間は木石も同然、悟りの境地ではござるが、世の役には立ち申さぬ。殿がかような生き仏になっては御国の大事。　いや、勝手な言い草おおいに結構！　殿**におかれては**どうか今後とも、自侭になさってくださりませい！」

Is putting におかれては instead of just に　makes it more of a honorific expression? Or is the meaning entirely different?

Comment: +1 but I would not use the kanji 「置く」 there because the phrase in question has nothing to do with 「置く」.  I would write it in kana without any hesitation.  If I had to use a kanji, I would use 「於く」.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/166252/m0u/):

> #### に‐おい‐て【に×於て】
>
> **３** （多くは下に「は」を伴って）上の人物・事柄を強く指示する意を表す。…こそ。

This usage does carry some honorific weight, but perhaps more importantly it puts emphasis on what you're talking about, as opposed to something else.

> 殿 **は** どうか今後とも、自侭になさってくださりませい

*You My Lord, keep doing as you wish*

> 殿 **におかれては** どうか今後とも、自侭になさってくださりませい

*As for you My Lord, keep doing as you wish*

The connotation here being that, nirvana may be wonderful for some people, but not for the shogun. Therefore, *as for* him, he may continue being self-centered.

Comment: Yes, a good answer.+1 For a compliment. [link](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/norinori_77777/20081119/1227074781) 
**敬意（～におかれては）高貴な人が主語である場合、まるで人ではなく場所であるかのように表現して、敬意を表します。「主語＋に」となるので、慣れればすぐにわかりますが、慣れないと、主語を見失いがちです。**

Comment: Translated : ( ～におかれては ) When Japanese speak about noble men, they "treat" them **as if not a person but a place in order to express their worship**. It takes "subject + に" . If you are not familiar with this pattern sometime it is quite likely you may lose which one is the subject but if you get familiar with it, it would be easier.

Comment: Please allow me to "answer" mine on the comment line because I think his ( her? ) answer is good.

Comment: But isn't it interesting to see, if you can read such an old text, you are almost a native. ( This text is as difficult as for the university exam ) ^^.